# rigid body issue

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

[image]

I'm using rigid body into those chains and ball. The angle of ball falling is so weird even thhough I put a lot more heavy mass than chains , and the animation is so slow from some reason than yesterday.

The chains are not even touching each other with rigid body, and there is space between chains.

[image]

here is my blender file
[image]

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Since I just built almost exactly the same last week, I would also think your file might help to check how you have realised it or else there are too many possible settings to ask for.

Comment: Agreed.. I think we need the share, to hunt your problem down quickly.

Comment: This is my blender file
[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=KNrqpKkW" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/KNrqpKkW/)

Comment: Hi. Please don't post essential information like links, file downloads or additional details in the comments section where it can be easily missed. Instead edit them into your original post with the [Edit] button above. Comments are transitory by nature, are hard to index or search for, and may be erased at any moment.

Answer (score 2):

Just apply scale on the chain objects (and all rigid bodies) and that will be much better.

In object mode, select them, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> and choose 'scale'.

[image]